# How to make Visual Studio (2019/2022) link to the normal runtime libraries during a debug build?

Tags: visual-studio, microsoft-runtime-library

The reason I want to do this is because the debug libraries are littered with extra "assertion" statements that take ages to start with during remote debugging.

I hope it's only to replace `Multi-threaded Debug DLL (/MDd)` with `Multi-threaded DLL (/MD)` in `Code Generation` -> `Runtime Library` but I wonder if there are other changes one has to take into account as well?

Comment: Hmm. Does changing the runtime library to the non-debug version actually work? I thought maybe there'd be missing "debug-related" symbols, or some such, that your base project references.

Comment: ... or maybe a run-time error about the wrong value of something like `_debug_level_`?

Comment: Well, in theory I hope it should work to store the debug symbols for local app only and call the normal run time libraries. I mean the calling the debug or normal library shouldn't matter regarding the call sequence and parameters. I'll gave it a try but got some odd errors like `error LNK2038: mismatch detected for '_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL'`.

Comment: Yeah - That mismatch was the error I alluded to in my second comment. Couldn't remember what the symbol was actually called. There is possibly a workaround, by *forcing* the value of that symbol to what it needs to be, but I'm not sure how to do that. Maybe Google that symbol, or look for it here on SO?

Comment: I'll try it again with a complete clean rebuild but it's a rather large code base so it might take a while. Any idea how to fool the linker to use the normal runtime libraries besides forcing _ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVE?

Comment: Here's a possibly relevant SO post: [Mixing debug and release library/binary - bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11658915/10871073)

Comment: Great, thanks! Found a similar one where he managed to fix things but without knowing how.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65894941/error-lnk2038-mismatch-detected-for-iterator-debug-level-value-2-doesnt

Comment: This is the answer I was looking for https://stackoverflow.com/a/55816027/1189659 ie it's doable. I'll just have to find where the debug definition is mixed up.

Comment: Got it working although VS behaves somewhat strangely. When I forced `_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL` to 2, VS automatically switched linking to test mode which outputs `*-test.exe`. But well, that's another issue I'll have to save for another time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is doable and also good practice for remote debugging big and complex applications also exlained in [Mixing debug and release library/binary - bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11658915/mixing-debug-and-release-library-binary-bad-practice/55816027#55816027).

Besides switching link libraries from `Multi-threaded Debug DLL (/MDd)` to `Multi-threaded DLL (/MD)` one needs to take into account debug macros like `_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL` which might otherwise conflict during linking. A typical error message that indicates such a conflic is `error LNK2038: mismatch detected for '_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL'`

Once all the conflicting macros have been resolved it will link to the standard runtime libraries but the debug symbols for the application remains.

Also, @Adrian Mole thanks for the assistans in this matter.